# tensorflow install: bazel build error: failed package loads

Tags: build, tensorflow, bazel

Everything was fined before got the following error:

## bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer

...
INFO: Loading package: @local_config_cc//
--> ERROR: Loading failed; build aborted.

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 and bazel 0.2.2.
Any idea to this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You may need bazel 0.3.0

Comment: Due to the problem on protobuff, I replaced bazel 0.3.0 with its 0.2.2. And because my servers are behind a proxy, I cannot access any external repository like git. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe this could use an issue on github, I've seen other people complaining about install not working on offline system ([#3071](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3071), [#3194](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3194))

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to bazel 0.3 system-wide

```
wget -O bazel-3.sh https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.3.0/bazel-0.3.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
chmod 755 bazel-3.sh
sudo ./bazel-3.sh
bazel version
```